# Kali Linux update error with sources.list

Tags: updates, kali-linux

i have Kali Linux on a virtual machine and i can't get updates with `apt-get update`it shows me this error:

```
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So i think the problem is in my sources.list because all the search i have done tells me that, however, the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` gives me:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Which i tried to add but didn't fix it
also when i used the upgrade command it upgraded most of the packages except some that i had to do `apt-get upgrade --fix-missing` to get them upgraded i don't know if that is important.

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease                         
Ign:4 http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates InRelease
Err:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:6 http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This is the full respond i get from the command `apt-get update`
so how do i get the update.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: so i figured i had to change the sources.list file to this

> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

> deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

now it loads for a little while and when its finished it shows another error which is

> Failed to fetch http://kali.download/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/source/Sources.gz  Hash Sum mismatch

> Hashes of expected file:
>
> - Filesize:13004030 [weak]
> - SHA256:41813ef30e9aff9f1d3e47c3e62db97e78671cca6efcf94c345e01e89f3ca132
> - SHA1:df027e74f6b9ccadd465fc033d2e4ebd35ef86c9 [weak]
> - MD5Sum:6246a24e60032c03892879386e9961ff [weak]
>   Hashes of received file:
> - SHA256:c58d9f5cb4e81fd866b7099e39cc49cb7f0f61a09ed332be8926d0a7b64dac98
> - SHA1:0f9aa18fcca3c7f44bde6a3acb85a1ce0c64bd93 [weak]
> - MD5Sum:129dff3ad7bfbd82cea9021295c98d37 [weak]
> - Filesize:13004030 [weak]
>   Last modification reported: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 00:05:53 +0000
>   Release file created at: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 00:06:41 +0000

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

and by the way it downloads the same file again when i try `apt-get update`

what to do now

Answer (score 0):

EXPLANATION and Solution: Quick Fix

This issue is caused by the Windows Hypervisor Platform. This issue cannot be resolved for now (asfar as I know).

A partial fix is at hand though. And I say"partial" because it involves disabling the platform (also known as"Hyper-V") which will probably break other virtualization solutions you have installed since this is enabled manually. Anyway, here's how to disable it and get your Kali VM running again,

1. Shut down the Kali Virtual Machine.
2. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then hit <kbd>A</kbd> to run Command Prompt(powershell) as administrator.
3. Type

   ```
    bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```
4. When you see "The operation completed succesfully", reboot your windows. After reboot, boot Kali and update/upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

Go into /etc/apt/sources.list and update the source path to: deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

https not http. You are trying to download repos using http what already have been displayed on your screen that it is not secure.

That is why you have errors.

Comment: now it gives me this error

Comment: Err:6 https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
  Cannot initiate the connection to mirror.karneval.cz:443 (2a02:8301:0:2::150). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirror.karneval.cz:443 (89.102.0.150). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 89.102.0.150 443]
Fetched 4,086 kB in 2h 4min 14s (548 B/s)        
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: E: Failed to fetch https://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to mirror.karneval.cz:443 (2a02:8301:0:2::150). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirror.karneval.cz:443 (89.102.0.150). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 89.102.0.150 443]

Comment: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score -2):

The key information here is:

E: Failed to fetch … Cannot initiate the connection

Or:

E: Failed to fetch ...  Connection timed out

Or:

Failed to fetch ...  Connection failed

That is, the system could not download some package files.

Cause of error:

You have an unstable internet connection and some files were not uploaded due to disconnections

Some time passed between updating the application cache and downloading files, during which the packages in the repository managed to be updated - that is, you are trying to download old packages, and are no longer available on the server, as they are replaced by new versions. Such a situation is likely, especially if you need to upgrade many packages, and your Internet connection is slow.

To solve the problem, simply restart the update with the commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade
```

This should completely correct the error.

Comment: thank you that fixed it and Sysadmin down voting is really annoying i tried to make the error as clear as possible